# Unrar and unzip simultaneously

Tags: tcl, unrar

I have a tcl script but that can only one decompress one thing at a time.
I must currently wait for the moment it has finished, before I can make the next. How do I do two things at once?

```
bind pubm - "*complete*" unrar

proc unrar {nick host handle channel text} {
    set text [stripcodes bcru $text]
    set name [lindex [split $text] 2];
    set dir "/tmp/unrar"
    if {[catch {exec /bin/sh -c "unrar e $dir/$name $dir/archive/$name"} error]} {
        putlog "error: $error";
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: where does the unzip come in? Doesn't appear in your code.

Comment: i have in $name .rar and .zip files, and wiht unrar unpack this, the problem is not the rar or zip, simultaneously is my problem, regards

Answer (score 1):

Tcl can do several things at once, particularly when it itself will be I/O-bound while doing the wait. To do this, we need to take advantage of the fact that eggdrop (I recognise that type of `bind`) is running the event loop, and use the `fileevent` command. The `fileevent` command is great because it lets us schedule some code to be run when “something happens” on a channel; when the channel is a pipeline (or socket) when can use a *readable* event to do something when there is some text to read or the channel is closed. (The difference is hard to tell apart until you actually read something.)

Let's put the bits together: pipelines and reporting back of results. I present the `asyncpipe` command!

```
proc asyncpipe {command lineCallback closedCallback} {
    set f [open |$command "r"]
    fileevent $f readable [list asyncpipe.callback $f $lineCallback $closedCallback]
    # There's no output from this command directly, and it returns nearly instantly if your pipeline is sensible.
}
proc asyncpipe.callback {channel lineCallback closedCallback} {
    if {[gets $channel line] >= 0} {
        uplevel "#0" $lineCallback [list $line]
    } elseif {[eof $channel]} {
        catch {close $channel}
        uplevel "#0" $closedCallback
    }
}
```

OK, that's build the basic machinery but it isn't particularly clear yet. Here's how to use it.

```
bind pubm - "*complete*" unrar

proc unrar {nick host handle channel text} {
    set text [stripcodes bcru $text]
    set name [lindex [split $text] 2];
    set dir "/tmp/unrar"
    asyncpipe [list unrar e $dir/$name $dir/archive/$name] \
        [list unrar.report putlog $name] [list unrar.done $name]
}
proc unrar.report {name line} {
    putlog "unrar $name :>> $line"
}
proc unrar.done {name} {
    putlog "all done with unrar $name"
}
```

This will report the output from unrar as it happens *and* it will let you run two at once. (Writing a “copy” that uses unzip instead is left as an exercise; it's a total cut-n-paste job except possibly for the arguments to unzip.) Asynchronous programming *is* a bit more complicated than what you're used to, but as long as you use named procedures for the callbacks you can work without getting too confused.

Ignore the machinery and concentrate on what's happening at the higher level. The rewritten `unrar` parses its arguments and asks for `unrar` to run asynchronously as a subprocess. Whenever there's output, it gets fired into `unrar.report` (one line at a time) which writes it to the log. You might want to report it elsewhere instead/as-well. When the pipeline finishes, `unrar.done` gets called so it can log that it's finished. I'm passing the name into `unrar.report` and `unrar.done` because then it's possible to see *what* is finished; knowing what's going on is occasionally a problem with async programs, so it helps to be exact. (That's a definite pro-tip!)

You can launch things as many times as you want at once. Do too many (how many depends on your hardware) and your computer will slow down, possibly *a lot*, but it'll eventually catch up.

Comment: Hello, dual unrar working, after unpack have 2 Proc [unrar] <defunct>
, and no output from putlog unrar.report and unrar.done

Comment: i have edit this from [list unrar.report putlog $name] to [list unrar.report $name]